# APK build size triple on ubuntu than of build on windows

Tags: android, windows, ubuntu, android-ndk, linphone

I have been working on some project, integrating linphone on windows. Then I decided to move my work to ubuntu system. In my android studio project there is folder named jniLibs under which various android architecture based generated binaries are present. The thing is after analysing the apk in android studio on both platform, I can see that the size of that folder is 12MB in windows and 57MB in ubuntu. I also tried to rebuild the exact code taken from windows.

Comment: Did you clone the entire project (inlcuding all build scripts) from a repository, or did you set up the new project manually? In the latter case, make sure that all build scripts are identical (e.g. that the abiFilters are the same, and that you're not building a debug apk on one system, and a release apk on the other).

Comment: I am pretty much sure that I am not building release build on one and debug on another. Also I have cloned the entire project. The Android view file structure shows the name of folder as jniLibs and on file system it is named as libs. The size of this folder is the main issue here rest of the things are good. Just the folder is having triple size than of the libs folder on windows.

Comment: The total size of the folder is not enough for diagnosis. Please check if both have same files with different sizes, or maybe the Ubuntu side includes files that don't appear on Windows.

Comment: Files(.so files) are exactly the same but the each one of them has increased file size on ubuntu machine

Comment: Are the shared libs not stripped on Ubuntu? What version of the NDK? What version of the gradle plugin?